# How to bind a WPF control to a property of an object which is in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, datacontext

I am new to WPF and learning how to bind the controls. I have created a UI which has different controls such as combobox and spinner (user defined control). Now I want to bind those controls such as combobox to a property of an object. Below is the sample code.

```
public class Parameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected decimal m_Code;

    public decimal CODE
    {
        get { return m_Code; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Code != value)
            {
                m_Code = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CODE");
            }
        }
    }

    protected decimal m_CurrentValue;

    public decimal CURRENT_VALUE
    {
        get { return m_CurrentValue; }
        set
        {
            if (m_CurrentValue != value)
            {
                m_CurrentValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CURRENT_VALUE");
            }
        }
    }

    protected Dictionary<int, string> m_ItemsDict;

    public Dictionary<int, string> ItemsDict
    {
        get { return m_ItemsDict; }
        set
        {
            //if (m_dict != value) Not comparing dictionaries. We should set if we get this request
            {
                m_ItemsDict = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsDict");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Below class is a singleton which has a dictionary where Key is an int and value is an object of parameter class.

```
public class ParameterDB: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static ParameterDB m_instance = new ParameterDB();

    public static ParameterDB Instance
    {
        get { return m_instance; }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, Parameter> m_ParamDict; 

    private ParameterDB()
    {
        m_ParamDict = new Dictionary<int, Parameter>();
        for(int i=0; i< 300; i++)
        {
            m_ParamDict.Add(i, new Parameter());
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, Parameter> ParamDict
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ParamDict;
        }

        set
        {
            m_ParamDict = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ParamDict");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Now I want to bind a control to, let's say,  ParamDict[0].CURRENT_VALUE. I have created a custom combo box class.

```
public class MyComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
{
    public readonly static DependencyProperty CodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Code",
        typeof(UInt32),
        typeof(FlexSIMComboBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(new UInt32()));

    public UInt32 Code
    {
        get { return (UInt32)GetValue(CodeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CodeProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public readonly static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(decimal),
        typeof(MyComboBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(new decimal(0), ValueChangedCallback));

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return (decimal)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void ValueChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyComboBox myComboBox = d as MyComboBox;

        if (myComboBox != null && e.NewValue is decimal)
        {
            // Check if new value is under the limit
            decimal newValue = (decimal)e.NewValue;
            myComboBox.SelectedValue = (int)newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML file:

```
<local:MyComboBox 
    Grid.Column="1" x:Name="myCBCtrl" Margin="0,0,0,7"   Width="180"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="true" 
    Code="{Binding CODE, Mode =TwoWay}" 
    Value="{Binding CURRENT_VALUE, Mode =TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsDict, Mode =TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" TargetUpdated="ComboBox_TargetUpdated"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

My question is how do I set DataContext for this control to an object which is in a dictionary?
For example to ParamDict[CODE]. CODE is also the key for the dictionary.

My intention is to build a dictionary and then bind my control to an item's property in that dictionary. So if the item's property is changed, it should reflect on the UI too. Any idea how to do that in XAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

```
<local:MyComboBox DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ParameterDB.Instance}}"
    Grid.Column="1" x:Name="myCBCtrl" Margin="0,0,0,7"   Width="180"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="true" 
    Code="{Binding Path=ParamDict[0].CODE, Mode =TwoWay}" 
    Value="{Binding Path=ParamDict[0].CURRENT_VALUE, Mode =TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParamDict[0].ItemsDict, Mode =TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" TargetUpdated="ComboBox_TargetUpdated"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```